# Why does this JSON object validate against this JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

The schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "const": "alice"
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/alice"
            }
        }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "alice": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "const": "alice"
                },
                "age": {
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            "required": ["name", "age"]
        }
    }
}
```

The object:

```
{
  "name": "bob"
}
```

Basically, I don't understand why even though the name is `bob` and I want the name to be one of `["alice"]`, the JSON object still passes the validation.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!  Turns out I just need to add `"else": false` to the `if-then-else` clause, or otherwise the schema still passes despite `if` failing.

So like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "const": "alice"
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/alice"
            },
            "else": false
        }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "alice": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "const": "alice"
                },
                "age": {
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            "required": ["name", "age"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the `if` key word is only to test if `then` or `else` should be applicable to that instance location. `if` by itself does nothing for validation.